# IE only browser using Absolute Positioning Right?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

**HTML**

```
<center>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="test_1">
                <div id="test_2">
                    <span id="test_3">[+]</span>
                    Test Test Test
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

This is my test Code:

here is the Test **CSS**:

```
div[id*='test_1'] {
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: #A4A4A4;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0px;

}
span[id*='test_3'] {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1q7zuq16/1/

The [+] should be all the way the left, while the text is centered.

If you open that jfiddle up in Firefox, Chrome, opera the [+] is over top the words.  If you open it up in IE, it works properly.

I use IE most so I'm wondering what I can do differently with my code to make the absolute positioned span, go to the far left of the div its positioned in, instead of aligning with the text.

Comment: Absolute positioning initially does not change where an element is rendered, only once you start applying top/right/bottom/left. Adding `left: 0;` fixes your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define the top or left value for the absolute position. By default their values are set to auto.

```
span#test_3 {/* attribute selector removed (optional - as it is just test_3 nothing more) */
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;/*put your value*/
    left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: `span[id='test_3']` should then be `span#test_3`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  I thought that when you set something to Absolute it automatically went to the top left corner.  I guess IE is "broken" and it does that but the others don't.  Thanks!  Also, I had that attribute selector in there because in my real code its needed, i just copy pasted, then changed the names to work with the test code.  Thank you again!  adding Top: 0px; and Left: 0px; did solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just float left?

```
span[id*='test_3'] {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    float:left;   
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1q7zuq16/2/